# PyQt5 QTableWidget How to re-enable a cell after disabling?

Tags: python, pyqt5

For the life of me I cant figure this out. I have a table set up, and in row 0 col 0 I have a checkbox. If that checkbox is not clicked I want to disable row 1, col 0. Otherwise if clicked, enable row 1 col 0.

To disable it I've been using flags:

```
if not self.example_table.cellWidget(0,0).isChecked():
    flags = QtCore.Qt.ItemFlags()
    flags != QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
    # flags != QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable (This also works to disable it)
    self.example_table.item(1,0).setFlags(flags)
```

The problem is that when I try and make an else with the inverse, it will not re-enable the cell. Here is what I've tried.

```
else:
    flags = QtCore.Qt.ItemFlags()
    flags == QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled #(still doesnt work)
    # flags = QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled (didnt work)
    # flags == QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable (didnt work)
    # flags = QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable (didnt work)

    self.tblActivityInfo.item(1, 0).setFlags(flags)
```

No matter what I try, the cell at 1,0 remains disabled.

self.example_table is just a QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing doesn't make much sense: both the second `flags` lines are just comparisons, they do absolutely nothing.

You should get the current flags for the existing item instead, and then use binary operators to update them.

```
item = self.example_table.item(1, 0)
flags = item.flags()
if not self.example_table.cellWidget(0,0).isChecked():
    # set the ItemIsEnabled flag bit to 0
    flags &= ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
else:
    # set the ItemIsEnabled flag bit to 1
    flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
    flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled

item.setFlags(flags)
```

I recommend you to better study what comparison operators do and how binary bitwise operations work.

Comment: So for whatever reason, this works to re-enable the cell, however I can not change the value there. I changed the 'ItemIsEnabled' to 'ItemIsEditable'. This did not re-enable the cell, however, so I added 'flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled' after. This works, thank you!

Comment: Yeah I too dont know why they were comparisons, but thats the code snipets I found on many, many different google searches. I also don't understand why the comparisons would make changes to the affect of the flags, but they did.

Comment: No, they didn't. It "worked" in the first case (disabling the item) because you created an "empty" flag (as in 0 value), which doesn't enable any flags (including, obviously, ItemIsEnabled).

Comment: That makes more sense. I feel like someone once answered the question with that, and it was copied over multiple times to different responses cause it "worked" to disable it.

Comment: That's very likely, unfortunately it's common to use code (especially here on SO) without actually understanding what it does. Anyway, I've seen your edit suggestion, and I don't understand it: `ItemIsEnabled` and `ItemIsEditable` are two very distinct flags, and they exist for a specific reason. Do you want to (dis|en)able the item or make it [un]editable?

Comment: You're right they are two different flags. For some reason, when I use just ItemIsEnabled, as in your original, it will disable the cell, then re-enable it. However, even though re-enabled, it is not editable for some reason. 

When just using ItemIsEditable, it will disable the cell (and look identical to a 'not' ItemIsEnabled cell. However, when I try to re-enable the cell using ItemIsEditable, it will still be grayed out and unclickable. Using the combination of the two calls worked though.